# Key-Frame Animation appears fuzzy when moving Frames?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uiview

I use [JazzHands](https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands) to create a key frame based animation in a UIScrollView.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/steffimueller/Intro-Guide-View-for-Talk.ai). Look at the view at the top. When you move from page to page. While the animation is running the view at the top is slightly moving from left to right. The animation appears a bit fuzzy.

Here is the code taken from the [example here](https://github.com/steffimueller/Intro-Guide-View-for-Talk.ai/blob/master/talkIntro/ViewController.m#L228-L239):

```
IFTTTFrameAnimation *titleView1FrameAnimation = [IFTTTFrameAnimation new];
    titleView1FrameAnimation.view = self.titleView1;
    [self.animator addAnimation:titleView1FrameAnimation];

    [titleView1FrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(1)
                                                                                    andFrame:self.titleView1.frame]];
    [titleView1FrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(2)
                                                                           andFrame:CGRectOffset(self.titleView1.frame, timeForPage(2), 0)]];
    [titleView1FrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(3)
                                                                           andFrame:CGRectOffset(self.titleView1.frame, timeForPage(3), 0)]];
    [titleView1FrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(4)
                                                                           andFrame:CGRectOffset(self.titleView1.frame, timeForPage(4), 0)]];
```

When running the [demo](https://github.com/steffimueller/Intro-Guide-View-for-Talk.ai) take a look at the part marked with red in the following screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Edit: Here is the code containing this problem: https://github.com/steffimueller/Intro-Guide-View-for-Talk.ai

**How can I make the animation running smooth and less fuzzy?**

Comment: Just to make sure. You want to get rid of the left and right moving of the top view?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if my expression is right but the top views are shaking horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the frame rate in the JazzHands `IFTTTAnimatedScrollViewController` being set for non-retina displays. You need to double the number in `timeForPage`, and also use double the number of the `contentOffset` in `animate`, but use the original non-doubled values of `timeForPage` in places where you were using that for laying out the positions of views instead of using it for the animation time.

Here's a Gist of the changes you'd have to make to your example to get it working. [Fixed Demo Gist](https://gist.github.com/lauraskelton/11cec6a14a963a912e7f)

You need this method for setting the animation times:

```
#define timeForPage(page) (NSInteger)(self.view.frame.size.width * (page - 1) * 2.0)
```

And this one for setting the centers of your views based on the page dimensions:

```
#define centerForPage(page) (NSInteger)(self.view.frame.size.width * (page - 1))
```

Then you need to override the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method in `IFTTTAnimatedScrollViewController` to use double the numbers it's currently using.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.animator animate:(NSInteger)(scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2)];
}
```

We'll work on getting the JazzHands demo updated!

Answer (score 0):

Before you start your animation call:

```
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES; (seems that you are using objective-c so I put YES here, for swift should be true)
```

As soon as the animation is finished call

```
view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO; (seems that you are using objective-c so I put NO here, for swift should be false)
```

You should always use it when you animating a view

You can see more details about it in the WWDC 2012 [Polishing Your Interface Rotations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=240) video (paid developer subscription needed)

I hope that helps you!

**[EDIT]**

Every Time you call the method animate set shouldRasterize to YES before it, like in the example bellow:

```
titleView1FrameAnimation.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
[self. titleView1FrameAnimation animate:scrollView.contentOffset.x];
```

Comment: When do I know in my case when animation starts and when it ends?

Comment: Correction (seems that you are using objective-c !xcode

Comment: Can you share your code so I can try to implement the solution in the code?

Comment: @Icaro Here is the code: https://github.com/steffimueller/Intro-Guide-View-for-Talk.ai

Answer (score 0):

I've messed around a bit with the code and it seems that keeping those top views in place while the scrollview is scrolling made it jiggle left and right.

What I did is take out the title view from the scroll view and add it to the view controller view.

You can see it in action [here](https://github.com/steffimueller/Intro-Guide-View-for-Talk.ai/pull/1)

**Later edit:**

To actually see what I've changed you can check the file differences in Git. Basically I moved your `titleView`s (`titleView1`, `titleView2`, etc) from the scrollView to the view controller's view (so basically I've replaced all the lines that were like this:

```
[self.scrollView addSubView:self.titleView1]
```

to something like this:

```
[self.view addSubView:self.titleView1]
```

After that I've also took out the keyframe animations that were keeping your title views in place since they were not moving with the scrollview anymore. Practically I've deleted all the lines that were adding a frame animation to your titleviews from each *configurePage**X**Animation*.

**2nd question answer:**

Say your screenshot view is called `screenshotView`. You can go ahead and create it like this:

```
UIImageView *screenshotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ScreenshotImage"]];
[self.view addSubview:screenshotView];
self.screenshotView = screenshotView;
[self.screenshotView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + self.view.bounds.size.width, <#yourDesiredY#>)];
```

And animate it like this:

```
//screenshotView frame animation
IFTTTFrameAnimation *screenshotViewFrameAnimation = [IFTTTFrameAnimation new];
screenshotViewFrameAnimation.view = self.screenshotView;
[self.animator screenshotViewFrameAnimation];

[screenshotViewFrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(1) andFrame:self.screenshotView.frame]];
[screenshotViewFrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(2) andFrame:CGRectOffset(self.screenshotView.frame, -self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0.0)]];
[screenshotViewFrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(3) andFrame:CGRectOffset(self.screenshotView.frame, -self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0.0)]];
[screenshotViewFrameAnimation addKeyFrame:[[IFTTTAnimationKeyFrame alloc] initWithTime:timeForPage(4) andFrame:CGRectOffset(self.screenshotView.frame, -self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * 2, 0.0)]];
```

Comment: Works good. I accept your answer. Could you please describe in more details what you have done?

Comment: Okay one last thing please. When you have a screenshot of your app on page 2 and 3. You want that it appears only when you are on page 2 and 3 (not on page1 or page4). After page3 it should move out of the screen to the left. How would you do that?

Comment: @MihaiFratu It would be nice if you could add this to your answer.

Comment: Check my updated answer once again. Please, next time don't ask people to answer multiple questions in the same thread. It would be more useful for people here on SO that you ask a separate question

Comment: @MihaiFratu I accept your answer but I will be happy if you could answer my last question too.

Comment: Man, I did answered your 2nd question also! Check out the answer update!